# predict vs forecast in var models

Tags: r, statistics, forecasting

Suppose you have a VAR model, and you want to know the future values of each series.

So what I was doing was estimating the var model using `VAR()` from `vars` package, then I was getting the forecast for every series using `forecast()` from `forecast` package.

But recently I saw that the `vars` package has a `predict` function.

Is there any difference between them?

Sorry if this is too basic or if I am misreading something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The return values of the method `predict.varest` and of `forecast` are different but the values can be found by reading the `Value` section of both help pages and the results can be compared.

Below, the difference between `predict.varest` and `forecast` is a time series of class `"ts"` and all zero values. The two ways of forecasting or preng from the fit are equivalent.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(vars))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(forecast))

data(Canada)

fit <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "none")
class(fit)
#> [1] "varest"

y1 <- predict(fit)
y2 <- forecast(fit)

class(y1)
#> [1] "varprd"
class(y2)
#> [1] "mforecast"

y1$fcst$e[, "fcst"] - y2$forecast$e$mean
#>      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
#> 2001    0    0    0    0
#> 2002    0    0    0    0
#> 2003    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>